# accesing an alias set in .gitlab-ci.yml in a node.js script

Tags: node.js, bash, gitlab

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker.x.x/vertica
cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/

job:
    script:
        - shopt -s expand_aliases
        - alias vsql="/opt/vertica/bin/vsql"
        - source /nvm
        - nvm install 8.9
        - nvm use
        - npm install
        - npm test
```

Error in my node.js test:

```
  1) Setup
       Should create test table for tests:

      AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: '/bin/sh: vsql: command not found\n' === ''
      + expected - actual

      -/bin/sh: vsql: command not found

      at Context.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:86:20)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37309112/1137669 but have no idea how to implement this in the `gitlab-ci.yml` file so that it can be accessed by the node.js script.

Comment: Defining an alias seems completely like the wrong approach. Just add `/opt/vertica/bin` to your `PATH` instead.

Comment: Having said that, `vsql () { /opt/vertica/bin/vsql "$@"; }` defines a function instead of an alias if you really think you need that.  `export -f vsql` exports it so that it can be used by subprocesses. But again, this is not a sane solution to a completely trivial problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a multiline script.

So:

```
job:
  script:
    - PATH=$$PATH:/opt/vertica/bin &&
      source /nvm &&
      nvm install 8.9 &&
      nvm use &&
      npm install &&
      npm test
```

Every entry in your `script` hash will be executed in a separate shell. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560083/multiline-yaml-string-for-gitlab-ci-gitlab-ci-yml) on how to use multiline scripts.

Comment: You add directories to the `PATH`, not individual binaries.

Comment: The OP's own answer is deleted but looks to me like a better solution. Not sure why it got negative feedback; but I'm not familiar with Gitlab, so I can't tell if it actually works. (It adds a `before_script` stanza which adds the vsql directory to the `PATH` (and like this one, an unnecessary but harmless `export`)).

Comment: @tripleee And how would the environment (which is process specific) from the before_script be passed on to the job script ? (i removed the useless eval from my answer btw.)

Comment: Hm, probably that was the problem then. You can remove the `export` too; the `PATH` variable is exported by definition.

Comment: @tripleee: `PATH` is exported by `default`, not by `definition`. If I unexport it, it will only affect the current shell and not its children. Try: 'unset PATH; /bin/bash -c 'export' | /bin/grep PATH`

Comment: Technically http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ allows for `PATH` to be unset or null so I guess that's basically correct. In practice, it's hard to find an environment where you are running a shell where `PATH` isn't already marked for export.